# Calculating a theoretical degree of polymerisation of ethylene oxide

Tags: stoichiometry, polymers

This is the problem: Researchers add 88 grams of ethylene oxide. This reacts fully to 92 grams of poly ethylene oxide. Calculate the degree of polymerisation.

[image: Polymerisation of ethylene oxide]

I thought: molecular weight of ethylene oxide is 44 grams. So you have 2 moles in 88 grams and when this polymerizes, you'll get 2 moles of monomers and thus n=2. However, the answer states that n=9.
This is the answer included in the test:

1. Calculating moles ethylene oxide: 88/44, - 1 point
2. Concluding that 4 g H20 reacted , - 1 point
3. Amount of moles formed of poly ethylene oxide (= amount of moles H2O reacted) =   4g H2O / 18, - 1 point
4. average n = amount of moles ethylene oxide that reacted / amount of moles of poly ethylene oxide formed - 1 point
5. Concluding that n=9, - 1 point

Thanks alot!

Comment: Hi orthocresol. U edited my thing but shouldn´t one of the O´s be outside the monomers... like it was before. Now the molecular weight of the monomer is 16 higher.